# Procurar uma string em dois arquivos .txt em C

Tags: c, string, arquivo, algoritmo-de-busca

Eu quero comparar uma string do arquivo de nomes com uma do arquivo de relato. Fiz isto, mas parece errado e está pulando algumas strings.

Conteúdo que está no arquivo relato.txt:

> Jose chegou de uma longa viagem vindo de Manacapuru no estado do
> Amazonas e entrou pela porta da sala da casa de Laura. Ela chegou pela
> cozinha com seu irmao Arthur, ao que Jose perguntou onde eles estavam
> e eles responderam: na casa da amiga Manuela. Infelizmente o relogio
> atrasou e ela marcava a hora que seu filho Matheus chegava de Coari
> (cidade vizinha). Na manha seguinte a televisao noticiou um acidente
> que ocorrera na cidade de Parintins onde varias pessoas ficaram
> feridas, inclusive Marcos e Roberto, conhecidos da familia.

Conteúdo que está dentro do arquivo nomes.txt:

```
Alice
Helena
Isabela
Julia
Laura
Livia
Luiza
Manuela
Sofia
Valentina
Arthur
Bernardo
Davi
Gabriel
Heitor
Lucca
Lorenzo
Miguel
Matheus
Pedro
```

Ele consegue achar a string Matheus, por exemplo, mas pula Laura e Manuela que vêm na frente.

```
//Mover o ponteiro em uma unidade a partir do inicio
fseek(arquivo_simbolos, 1, SEEK_SET);
fseek(arquivo_principal, 1, SEEK_SET);
//Posicionar na posicao inicial
rewind(arquivo_simbolos);
rewind(arquivo_principal);
//Percorrer arquivos
do{
    //Enquanto não chegar no fim do arq principal
    while( !feof(arquivo_principal) ){
        //Pegar uma string do arquivo principal
        fscanf(arquivo_principal, "%s", vet_principal);
        //Enquanto não " " do arq de simbolos
        while( !feof(arquivo_simbolos) ){
            //Pegar uma string do arquivo de simbolos
            fscanf(arquivo_simbolos, "%s", vet_simbolos);
            //Ver se as strings são iguais
            if( strcmp(vet_principal, vet_simbolos ) == 0){
                //Achou
                bandeira_3 = 1;
                printf("Achou!");
                printf("%s %s ", vet_principal, vet_simbolos);
            }else{
                //Não achou
                bandeira_3 = 0;
            }
        }
        //Reposicionar arquivo de simbolos no inicio
        rewind(arquivo_simbolos);
        fseek(arquivo_principal, 1, SEEK_CUR);
    }
}while(bandeira_3 != 1);
```

No meu código usei dois `while`, um para varrer o arquivo de relatos (arquivo_principal) e outro para o arquivo de nomes (arquivo_simbolos). Então uso `fscanf` para armazenar nas variáveis vetores uma string dos respectivos arquivos e uso a função `strcmp` para compará-las.

Usei um `do`/`while` para repetir caso não esteja achando a string. Por isso reposiciono o `arquivo_simbolos` com a função `rewind`.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Minha pergunta está objetiva.

Comment: Em vez de ficar indo e voltando no arquivo (e lendo-o várias vezes), uma alternativa melhor é guardar os nomes em um array, e depois para cada palavra do arquivo relato.txt, vc verifica se a palavra é um dos nomes deste array. Algo assim: https://replit.com/@hkotsubo/BuscarNomesArquivo#main.c

Comment: @hkotsubo, muito obrigado pela ajuda! A sua forma ficou excelente. Eu testei e está certa. Além do mais, ela é muito simples. Fico honrado de ser respondido por você. A paz!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando múltiplos `rewind()` e `fseek()` vai deixar tudo muito lento. E também não está fácil de ler.

Vou deixar um exemplo de como fazer isso usando uma técnica comum e abrindo cada arquivo uma única vez. A idéia é usar uma estrutura de dados e nesse caso uma variação de uma árvore de prefixos, chamada *Trie* na literatura.

#### Exemplo da estrutura

Sejam os nomes `azul`, `ama`, `ver` e `amar`

```
         a            v
       /   \            \
      m     z             e
     /       \              \
    a*        u               r*
   /           \ 
  r*            l*
```

A idéia é que não se precisa repetir os prefixos para todos os nomes. Os nomes já saem ordenados da estrutura e ainda há lugar para algumas otimizações, como compactar os dados quando só há uma palavra num certo ramo. O asterisco indica o fim de uma palavra e assim *amar* e *ama* por exemplo não repetem o prefixo.

#### A árvore em C

```
typedef struct st_tree
{
    size_t size;   // em nodes
    size_t words;  // em palavras
    Node*  root;   // raiz
} Tree;
```

E um nó seria

```
typedef struct st_node
{
    char            letra;  // cada node tem uma letra
    char            fim;    // termina uma palavra aqui?
    struct st_node* L;      // letra antes
    struct st_node* R;      // letra depois
    struct st_node* S;      // letras abaixo deste

} Node;
```

Essa função

```
Tree* def_dicionario(const char* arquivo)
{
    char linha[LIMITE_PAL];
    if (arquivo == NULL) return NULL;
    FILE* arq = fopen(arquivo, "r");
    if (arq == NULL) return NULL;
    char* p     = fgets(linha, sizeof(linha), arq);
    Tree* nomes = create();
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        if (*p != '\n')  // linha em branco?
        {
            if (linha[strlen(linha) - 1] == '\n')
                linha[strlen(linha) - 1] = 0;
            add(linha, &nomes->root, nomes);
        }
        p = fgets(linha, sizeof(linha), arq);
    }
    fclose(arq);
    return nomes;
}
```

recebe o nome do arquivo e retorna o endereço de uma árvore com todas as palavras, já em ordem como no exemplo, considerando um arquivo simples com um nome por linha.

#### As palavras e o arquivo 'relato.txt'

Um problema em seu código é que não está claro quais letras são válidas na string e o que delimita uma delas.

Uma maneira simples pode ser essa: uma tabela de 256 posições onde os símbolos que são aceitos para compor a string são passados por uma função.

#### exemplo

```
char* def_letras(const char* valido)
{
    char* tbl = (char*)malloc(256);
    if (tbl == NULL) return NULL;
    memset(tbl, 0, 256);
    const char* p = valido;
    while (*p != 0) *(tbl + *p++) = 1;
    return tbl;
}
```

Essa função resolve isso e é uma solução comum. Qual a idéia? É chamada assim

```
    char* valido = def_letras(
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxywz"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYWZ");
```

E assim na tabela retornada apenas essas letras estarão marcadas e não precisa testar nada. Trata-se de uma *look-up table*. E mudar a definição fica simples e direto. Para aceitar apenas números e alguns operadores por exemplo:

```
    char* exemplo = def_letras(
        "0123456789"
        " +-*/()=.");
```

#### juntando a tabela e a árvore

Então se os nomes já estão na estrutura e os caracteres válidos já estão na tabela basta ler o arquivo uma única vez, usando a tabela para extrair as strings e buscando na árvore o nome como se faria numa folha de papel. E é muito rápido. Algo assim

```
int busca_palavras(
    Tree* lista, const char* delim, const char* arquivo)
{
    char palavra[LIMITE_PAL];
    char pos = 0;
    if (arquivo == NULL) return 0;
    FILE* arq = fopen(arquivo, "r");
    if (arq == NULL) return 0;
    int  letra = fgetc(arq);
    char st    = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        if (feof(arq)) break;
        if (delim[letra] != 0)
            st = 1, palavra[pos++] = letra;
        if ((st == 1) && (delim[letra] == 0))
        {
            palavra[pos] = 0;
            if (nome_valido(palavra, lista))
                printf("+ \"%s\"\n", palavra);
            pos = 0;
            st  = 0;
        }
        letra = fgetc(arq);
    };  // while()
    fclose(arq);
    return 0;
}
```

Que é chamado assim no exemplo

```
    char* valido = def_letras(
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxywz"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYWZ");

    busca_palavras(nomes, valido, "relato.txt");
```

E faz sentido: vai ler o arquivo e usando a lista de letras aceitas vai extrair as palavras e buscar no dicionário `nomes`.

#### main para o exemplo

```
#include "tree.h"

int main(void)
{
    Tree* nomes = def_dicionario("nomes.txt");
    if (nomes == NULL) return -1;

    mostra_palavras(nomes, "Nomes encontrados:");

    char* valido = def_letras(
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxywz"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYWZ");
    mostra_letras_ok(valido, "\nLetras validas na string:\n");

    printf("\nNomes encontrados no arquivo:\n");
    busca_palavras(nomes, valido, "relato.txt");
    nomes = destroi_dicionario(nomes);
    free(valido);
    return 0;
}
```

- cria o dicionário com os nomes
- mostra os nomes encontrados, só para confirmar
- define as letras que podem formar uma string, no exemplo apenas letras maiúsculas e minúsculas
- mostra as letras aceitas, só para confirmar. Algo simples assim

```
int mostra_letras_ok(const char* lt, const char* titulo)
{
    if (titulo != NULL) printf("%s", titulo);
    char col = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i += 1)
    {
        if (*(i + lt) != 0)
        {
            printf("%c ", i);
            if (col == 10) printf("\n");
            col = (col == 10) ? 1 : col + 1;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

mostra

```
Letras validas na string:
A B C D E F G H I J
K L M N O P Q R S T
U V W X Y Z a b c d
e f g h i j k l m n
o p q r s t u v w x
y z
```

- busca os nomes no arquivo `relato``e mostra na tela
- apaga as estruturas

#### Saída do Exemplo

```
Nomes encontrados:
109 nodes, 20 palavras

Palavras:
                [Alice]
                [Arthur]
                [Bernardo]
                [Davi]
                [Gabriel]
                [Heitor]
                [Helena]
                [Isabela]
                [Julia]
                [Laura]
                [Livia]
                [Lorenzo]
                [Lucca]
                [Luiza]
                [Manuela]
                [Matheus]
                [Miguel]
                [Pedro]
                [Sofia]
                [Valentina]

Letras validas na string:
A B C D E F G H I J
K L M N O P Q R S T
U V W X Y Z a b c d
e f g h i j k l m n
o p q r s t u v w x
y z

Nomes encontrados no arquivo:
+ "Laura"
+ "Arthur"
+ "Manuela"
+ "Matheus"
```

#### O código completo

`tree.h`

```
#pragma once

#define LIMITE_PAL 80
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct st_node
{
    char            letra;  // cada node tem uma letra
    char            fim;    // termina uma palavra aqui?
    struct st_node* L;      // letra antes
    struct st_node* R;      // letra depois
    struct st_node* S;      // letras abaixo deste

} Node;

typedef struct st_tree
{
    size_t size;   // em nodes
    size_t words;  // em palavras
    Node*  root;   // raiz
} Tree;

int   busca_palavras(Tree* lista,const char* letras_validas,const char* arquivo);
Tree* def_dicionario(const char*);
char* def_letras(const char*);
Tree* destroi_dicionario(Tree*);
int   mostra_letras_ok(const char*, const char*);
int   nome_valido(const char*,Tree*);
int   mostra_palavras(Tree*, const char*);
```

`tree.c`

```
#include "tree.h"

// helpers
int   add(const char*, Node**, Tree*);
Tree* create();
Node* create_node(char);
Node* destroi_nodes(Node*);

Node* find_subt(const char, Node**, Tree*);
int   find_all_words(Node*, size_t);

// insere *pal a partir de *raiz na arvore *arv
// nivel, porque pode mudar com *pal
int add(const char* pal, Node** raiz, Tree* arv)
{
    if (arv == NULL) return -1;   // erro
    if (*pal == 0) return 0;      // ok
    if (raiz == NULL) return -1;  // erro
    // encontra ramo da arvore com essa letra
    // ou cria se nao tiver ainda
    Node* subt = find_subt(*pal, raiz, arv);
    // subt aponta para a sub-arvore da letra
    if (*(1 + pal) == 0)
    {
        subt->fim = 1;
        arv->words += 1;
        return 1;
    }
    return add(1 + pal, &subt->S, arv);
}

Tree* create()
{
    Tree* nova = (Tree*)malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    if (nova == NULL) return NULL;
    nova->size  = 0;
    nova->words = 0;
    nova->root  = NULL;
    return nova;
}

Node* create_node(char letra)
{
    Node* node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (node == NULL) return NULL;
    node->letra = letra;
    node->fim   = 0;
    node->L     = NULL;
    node->R     = NULL;
    node->S     = NULL;
    return node;
}

// busca palavras da lista no arquivo considerando
// a tabela de letras validas
int busca_palavras(
    Tree* lista, const char* delim, const char* arquivo)
{
    char palavra[LIMITE_PAL];
    char pos = 0;
    if (arquivo == NULL) return 0;
    FILE* arq = fopen(arquivo, "r");
    if (arq == NULL) return 0;
    int  letra = fgetc(arq);
    char st    = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        if (feof(arq)) break;
        if (delim[letra] != 0)
            st = 1, palavra[pos++] = letra;
        if ((st == 1) && (delim[letra] == 0))
        {
            palavra[pos] = 0;
            if (nome_valido(palavra, lista))
                printf("+ \"%s\"\n", palavra);
            pos = 0;
            st  = 0;
        }
        letra = fgetc(arq);
    };  // while()
    fclose(arq);
    return 0;
}

// retorna uma arvore com as palavras que estao no arquivo
Tree* def_dicionario(const char* arquivo)
{
    char linha[LIMITE_PAL];
    if (arquivo == NULL) return NULL;
    FILE* arq = fopen(arquivo, "r");
    if (arq == NULL) return NULL;
    char* p     = fgets(linha, sizeof(linha), arq);
    Tree* nomes = create();
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        if (*p != '\n')  // linha em branco?
        {
            if (linha[strlen(linha) - 1] == '\n')
                linha[strlen(linha) - 1] = 0;
            add(linha, &nomes->root, nomes);
        }
        p = fgets(linha, sizeof(linha), arq);
    }
    fclose(arq);
    return nomes;
}

char* def_letras(const char* valido)
{
    char* tbl = (char*)malloc(256);
    if (tbl == NULL) return NULL;
    memset(tbl, 0, 256);
    const char* p = valido;
    while (*p != 0) *(tbl + *p++) = 1;
    return tbl;
}

Tree* destroi_dicionario(Tree* dict)
{
    if (dict == NULL) return NULL;
    if (dict->root == NULL)
    {
        free(dict);
        return NULL;
    }
    Node* nd = dict->root;
    if (nd->R != NULL) destroi_nodes(nd->R);
    if (nd->S != NULL) destroi_nodes(nd->S);
    free(nd);
    free(dict);
    return NULL;
}

Node* destroi_nodes(Node* node)
{
    if (node == NULL) return NULL;
    Node* nd = node;
    if (nd->R != NULL) destroi_nodes(nd->R);
    if (nd->S != NULL) destroi_nodes(nd->S);
    free(nd);
    return NULL;
}

int mostra_letras_ok(const char* lt, const char* titulo)
{
    if (titulo != NULL) printf("%s", titulo);
    char col = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i += 1)
    {
        if (*(i + lt) != 0)
        {
            printf("%c ", i);
            if (col == 10) printf("\n");
            col = (col == 10) ? 1 : col + 1;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

// mostra na tela a palavra encontrada no arquivo
// se ela esta no dicionario
int nome_valido(const char* nome, Tree* lista)
{
    if (nome == NULL) return 0;
    if (lista == NULL) return 0;
    Node* dict = lista->root;
    while (dict != NULL)
    {
        if (dict->letra > *nome) return 0;
        if (dict->letra < *nome)
        {
            dict = dict->R;
            continue;
        }
        // ok tem a letra
        nome += 1;       // passa para a proxima letra
        dict = dict->S;  // desce na arvore
    };                   // while()
    if (*nome == 0) return 1;
    return 0;
};

// retorna endereco do ramo de *arv onde esta
// a letra 'letra'. Cria se nao existir
// pode alterar *ramo se mudar o inicio da lista
// de letras
Node* find_subt(const char letra, Node** ramo, Tree* arv)
{
    if (letra == 0) return NULL;   // sem letra
    if (arv == NULL) return NULL;  // sem arvore
    if (*ramo == NULL)
    {
        *ramo = create_node(letra);
        arv->size += 1;
        return *ramo;
    }
    Node* p      = *ramo;
    Node* nv     = NULL;
    char  estado = 1;
    while (1)
    {
        switch (estado)
        {
            case 1:
                if (p->letra < letra)
                {
                    if (p->R != NULL)
                        p = p->R;  // continua
                    else
                        estado = 3;  // acabou: poe no fim
                    break;
                }
                if (p->letra == letra) return p;
                // letra maior que p->letra: insere antes
                estado = 2;
                break;

            case 2:
                // fim da linha: nao tem a letra:
                // vai inserir ANTES de p
                nv = create_node(letra);
                arv->size += 1;
                if (p->L != NULL)
                {
                    p->L->R = nv;
                    nv->L   = p->L;
                    nv->R   = p;
                    p->L    = nv;
                }
                else
                {  // nv vai ser o novo inicio
                    nv->L = NULL;
                    nv->R = p;
                    p->L  = nv;
                    *ramo = nv;
                }
                return nv;
                break;

            case 3:
                // insere no fim das letras
                // p aponta para a ultima letra
                // mas e menor que 'letra'
                nv = create_node(letra);
                arv->size += 1;
                p->R  = nv;
                nv->L = p;
                return nv;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        };  // switch()
    };      // while()
    return NULL;
}

int find_all_words(Node* node, size_t pos)
{
    static char palavra[1024];  // 1K limite
    palavra[pos] = 0;
    Node* p      = node;
    palavra[pos] = p->letra;
    if (p->fim == 1)
    {
        palavra[pos + 1] = 0;
        printf("\t\t[%s]\n", palavra);
    }
    if (p->S != NULL) find_all_words(p->S, 1 + pos);
    if (p->R != NULL) find_all_words(p->R, pos);
    return 0;
}

int mostra_palavras(Tree* arv, const char* tit)
{
    if (tit != NULL) printf("%s\n", tit);
    if (arv == NULL) return 0;
    if (arv->root == NULL)
    {
        printf("dicionario vazio\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf(
        "%d nodes, %d palavras\n", arv->size, arv->words);
    printf("\nPalavras:\n");
    find_all_words(arv->root, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

`main.c`

```
#include "tree.h"

int main(void)
{
    Tree* nomes = def_dicionario("nomes.txt");
    if (nomes == NULL) return -1;

    mostra_palavras(nomes, "Nomes encontrados:");

    char* valido = def_letras(
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxywz"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYWZ");
    mostra_letras_ok(valido, "\nLetras validas na string:\n");

    printf("\nNomes encontrados no arquivo:\n");
    busca_palavras(nomes, valido, "relato.txt");
    nomes = destroi_dicionario(nomes);
    free(valido);
    return 0;
}
```

#### `nomes.txt`

```
Alice
Helena
Isabela
Julia
Laura
Livia
Luiza
Manuela
Sofia
Valentina
Arthur
Bernardo
Davi
Gabriel
Heitor
Lucca
Lorenzo
Miguel
Matheus
Pedro
```

#### `relato.txt`

```
Jose chegou de uma longa viagem vindo de Manacapuru no estado do 
Amazonas e entrou pela porta da sala da casa de Laura. 
Ela chegou pela cozinha com seu irmao Arthur, ao que Jose 
perguntou onde eles estavam e eles responderam: na casa da
amiga Manuela. Infelizmente o relogio atrasou e ela marcava
a hora que seu filho Matheus chegava de Coari (cidade vizinha).
Na manha seguinte a televisao noticiou um acidente que
ocorrera na cidade de Parintins onde varias pessoas ficaram
feridas, inclusive Marcos e Roberto, conhecidos da familia.
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o erro no seu codigo seja porque nem todas as palavras dentro do arquivo terminam com um espaço em branco (' '), algumas terminam com ponto, outras com vírgula. Aqui está um código que faz essa checagem:

Repare principalmente na função `equalsAny`: que checa um caractere contra um array de caracteres.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *findNextString(const char *fileName, long startPosition, long *output, short *foundEOF);
int equalsAny(char c, char arrChar[], size_t size);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char text_FileName[] = "Text.txt";
    char strings_fileName[] = "Strings.txt";

    long text_countCharsMoved;
    long text_filePosition = 0;
    short text_foundEOF = 0;
    do
    {
        char * text_Output = findNextString(text_FileName, text_filePosition, &text_countCharsMoved, &text_foundEOF);
        long text_sizeString = text_countCharsMoved - 1;
        text_filePosition += text_countCharsMoved;

        long strings_countCharsMoved;
        long strings_filePosition = 0;
        short strings_foundEOF = 0;
        do
        {
            char * strings_Output = findNextString(strings_fileName, strings_filePosition, &strings_countCharsMoved, &strings_foundEOF);
            long sizeString = strings_countCharsMoved - 1;
            strings_filePosition += strings_countCharsMoved;

            if (strcmp(text_Output, strings_Output) == 0)
            {
                printf("Exist in both files: %s\n", strings_Output);
                break;
            }

            free(strings_Output);
        } while (1 != strings_foundEOF);


        free(text_Output);
    } while (1 != text_foundEOF);


    return 0;
}

char * findNextString(const char * fileName, long startPosition, long * output, short * foundEOF)
{
    static char separators[] = { ' ', '\n', ',', '.', EOF };
    FILE *f = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if (NULL != f)
    {
        fseek(f, startPosition, SEEK_SET);

        unsigned int countChars = 0;

        char c = 0;
        do
        {
            c = fgetc(f);

            if (equalsAny(c, separators, sizeof(separators) / sizeof(separators[0])))
            {
                if (EOF == c) *foundEOF = 1;

                fseek(f, startPosition, SEEK_SET);

                char * result = malloc((countChars * sizeof(char)) + 1);

                for (size_t i = 0; i < countChars; i++)
                {
                    char c = fgetc(f);
                    result[i] = c;
                }
                result[countChars] = '\0';

                fclose(f);

                countChars++;
                *output = countChars;

                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                countChars++;
            }
        } while (EOF != c);
        fclose(f);
    }

    return 0;
}

int equalsAny(char c, char arrChar[], size_t size)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (c == arrChar[i])
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Eu acredito que seja por causa disto mesmo. Vou adaptar o seu código no meu para ver se sem os caracteres as palavras são encontradas. Obrigado!